# In SAPUI5 SmartTable on event beforeRebindTable adding some filters

Tags: sapui5

My requiremnt is to put some filters on smartTable form my controller.

In Event beforeRebindTable  i am using the following code to put filter using this code which is working fine.

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
  var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
  statFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Claim_TYPE", "EQ", "1234");
  oBindingParams.filters.push(statFilter);
}
```

But the problem is when the user is clicling  on table column on filter again, the filter i am adding in above code is not visible in the selection dialog. User may need to delete this filter, If its not visible in dialog they wont be able to delete it.

I am not able to establish the link why the dialog is not getting updated, or should i add this somewhere else.
Thanks
Sonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
        var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource();
        if (this._isOnInit == null) this._isOnInit = true;
        if (this._isOnInit) {
            oSmartTable.applyVariant(
                {
                    filter: {
                        filterItems: [{
                            columnKey: "YourSelectedColumn",
                            exclude: false,
                            operation: "EQ",
                            value1: "SomeEnteredValue",
                            value2: ""
                        }]
                    }
                }

            );
            this._isOnInit = false;
        }
    }
```